# Iterating over a list - to make lists

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, variables, nested-lists

The following code has a list called 'list_a' - that is looped through 4 times.

```
list_a=['red','green','blue', 'yellow']

list_1=[]
for i in list_a[0]:
    list_1.append(i)
print(list_1)

list_2=[]
for i in list_a[1]:
    list_2.append(i)
print(list_2)

list_3=[]
for i in list_a[2]:
    list_3.append(i)
print(list_3)

list_4=[]
for i in list_a[3]:
    list_4.append(i)
print(list_4)
```

If you were to iterate over each element in 'list_a' and split each letter into a string - you could do it as per the code above. But, is there a way to write shorter code - rather than writing the same code each time you loop through an element of 'list_a'.

For example - my attempt at it is:

```
list_a=['red','green','blue', 'yellow']

number=0
while number<len(list_a):
    list_(int(number+1))=[]
    for i in list_a[number]:
        list_(int(number+1)).append(i)
    print(list_(int(number+1))
number+=1
```

Hope you can help - thankyou.

Comment: You are looking for list comprehension my friend

Comment: It's helpful in questions like this to explicitly tell us what your hoped-for output it.  To get lists you can simply: `[list(l) for l in list_a]`, but it's not clear if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest code:

```
[[*a] for a in list_a]
```

Output:

```
[['r', 'e', 'd'], ['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n'], ['b', 'l', 'u', 'e'], ['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w']]
```

Explanation: `*a` is called unpacking and when applied to a string, unpacks it into individual characters. `[*a]` means we are unpacking it to a list. Only works on Python 3.

Comment: Didnt see that coming. Good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
list_a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
list_b = [[ch for ch in word] for word in list_a]
print(list_b)
```

Output:

```
[['r', 'e', 'd'], ['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n'], ['b', 'l', 'u', 'e'], ['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w']]
```

Or perhaps:

```
list_a = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
for word in list_a:
    print([ch for ch in word])
```

Result:

```
['r', 'e', 'd']
['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n']
['b', 'l', 'u', 'e']
['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
list_a=['red','green','blue', 'yellow']
output_lst = []
for word in list_a:
    temp = []
    for char in word:
        temp.append(char)
    output_lst.append(temp)
print(output_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Second Code (Attempt) You Can't Define List Names Like You Did In Your Code(Python Doesn't Work Like That), Instead You Have To Make A List Of List (Nested List) To Solve This Problem. I Am Attaching Sample Code To Solve This And It's Output.**

*Sample Code*

```
lst=[list(i) for i in list_a]
```

*Letting list_a Be*

```
list_a=['red','green',]
```

*Its Output*

> [['r', 'e', 'd'],['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'n']]

***As You Saw, It's Nested List Containing Each Element***

Answer (score 0):

This is the short way of getting the same output:

**Code:**

```
list_a=['red','green','blue', 'yellow']

for word in list_a:
    print(list(word))
```

**Output:**

```
['r', 'e', 'd']
['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n']
['b', 'l', 'u', 'e']
['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w']
```

Answer (score 0):

While iterating through each element in `list_a`, use a list comprehension to store each letter as a string in another list. I tried the below code :

```
list_a=['red','green','blue', 'yellow']
list_b=[]
for i in list_a:
    list_b.append([j for j in i])
for i in list_b:
    print(i)
```

Here `list_b` contains sub-lists for each string in `list_a`. Each sub-list contains all the characters of a string as a seperate string.

This gave the following output :

```
C:\User\Python>python script.py
['r', 'e', 'd']
['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n']
['b', 'l', 'u', 'e']
['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w']
```